# How can I autolink @mentions in my adapter itemview?

Tags: java, android, linkify

I'm using Linkify to search for strings that come after the `@symbol`. Why don't they turn into links in my TextView? Do I have to set something else in the XML like `android:linksClickable="true"`?

```
feedItemView.messageText.setText(message.getString("messageText"));
Pattern userMatcher = Pattern.compile("\\B@[^:\\s]+");
String userViewURL = ".activity.UserProfileActivity://";
Linkify.addLinks(feedItemView.messageText, userMatcher, userViewURL);
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Does not the @-references become links? Or are not the links what you need? Are you sure that your map's messageText has the right format?

Comment: @LeonardoAcevedo The mentions don't become links. I want them to be links. I just can't see what's wrong here.

Comment: I removed ``android:autoLink="all"`` from the XML. The above code also works. I wrote a new answer as well below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code:

```
feedItemView.messageText.setText(yeet.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_TEXT));

Linkify.TransformFilter filter = (match, url) -> match.group();

Pattern mentionPattern = Pattern.compile("@([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)");
String mentionScheme = "http://www.twitter.com/";
Linkify.addLinks(feedItemView.messageText, mentionPattern, mentionScheme, null, filter);
```

I also made sure to remove `android:autoLink="all"` from that TextView's XML. This will remove auto link functionality for web links so then you'd want to add this to method that handles displaying that TextView:

```
Pattern urlPattern = Patterns.WEB_URL;
Linkify.addLinks(tweet, urlPattern, null, null, filter);
```